# Registration plugin, accessing registration data

Tags: facebook, registration

I would like to develop a website using the Facebook Registration plugin. However, I would like to see whether it is possible to avoid having to save the registration data also on the website's own database.

The application is very simple, and it seems redundant that we need to save all the user data again just so we can pick up a random registration and notify a winner.

I have no problem implementing the plugin successfully, but I cannot seem to find a way to browse the registration data either at the Facebook Apps or using Open Graph.

Anybody knows whether it is possible to browse the registration data if it hasn't been saved on a custom database?

Thanks in advance,
Jorge

Answer (score 0):

Check out the "Reading the data" section of https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/

It says your information will come to you in the `signed_request` parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, that indicates that the data come for every registration at a time, and you still have to handle that data and likely save it on our own database. I would like to try to avoid that just by letting Facebook handle the registrations on my site. I just need a way to then know who registered...

Comment: Then use https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/, there's nothing to store on your side.